# How to write a postgresql TRIGGER that raises Warning message after INSERTING a certain incorrect numeric value into the EXISTING sql table column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add a trigger that raises a warning message when a certain out of bounds (not 2, 3, 5-7) numeric value is inserted into or altered in an EXISTING row in a "grade" column in the sql table. This code example raises such a message ONLY when a NEW row is created.

1. How to raise the message when a value in the EXISTING row is altered?
2. Values in the "grade" column are tied via key to a column in another table "grade_salary" where they are stored. How to write the insertion/alteration check in such a way that raises the message without specifying the concrete correct values (2, 3, 5-7), but stating only that "IF changed value lies outside of the values specified in column "grade" of the table "grade_salary" THEN raise the error message" (and not let the value be modified)?

> 

```
CREATE TRIGGER person
BEFORE INSERT ON hr."position"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE person();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person()
RETURNS TRIGGER
SET SCHEMA 'hr'
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
IF ((NEW.grade < 2) or (NEW.grade > 3 and NEW.grade < 5)
or (NEW.grade > 7)) THEΝ
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Incorrect value';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: This is what a `FOREIGN KEY` is for. Add one from `position.grade` to `grade_salary.grade`. FYI, a `FOREIGN KEY`  behind the scenes is a system trigger.

Answer (score 0):

One checks whether the new value corresponds to an existing one in a column with:

```
IF new_value not in (SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM grade_salary)
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Inadmissible value.'
```

In full:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person()
RETURNS TRIGGER
SET SCHEMA 'hr'
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare 
new_value numeric;
begin
  select new.grade from "position" into new_value;
IF new_value not in (SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM grade_salary)
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Inadmissible value.';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: 1) The above is the long an inefficient way of doing: `ALTER TABLE hr.position ADD CONSTRAINT grade_fk FOREIGN KEY (grade) REFERENCES grade_salary(grade) ON UPDATE CASCADE;` 2) The above can be simplified to: `IF NEW.grade not in (SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM grade_salary)` without the `select ... into ...`.